List specific information of all LEAF certificates from java store JKS
I wish to list only the signed certificates for our application and not the chain signing certificate from a java store i.e <jdk_home>/jre/lib/security/cacerts or any such JKS store.
The idea that comes to mind is I will grab the value of CN= from the Owner:  and check if it is present under Issuer:  anywhere in the entire store. If found then it is not the signed cert but the signer's cert.
keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts -storepass "changeit"

Output:
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 107 entries

*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: verisignuniversalrootca [jdk]
Creation date: Aug 25, 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority, OU="(c) 2008 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
Issuer: CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority, OU="(c) 2008 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
Serial number: 401ac46421b31321030ebbe4121ac51d
Valid from: Tue Apr 01 19:00:00 CDT 2008 until: Tue Dec 01 17:59:59 CST 2037
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: 36:79:CA:35:66:87:72:30:4D:30:A5:FB:87:3B:0F:A7:7B:B7:0D:54
         SHA256: 23:99:56:11:27:A5:71:25:DE:8C:EF:EA:61:0D:DF:2F:A0:78:B5:C8:06:7F:4E:82:82:90:BF:B8:60:E8:4B:3C
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.12 Criticality=false
0000: 30 5F A1 5D A0 5B 30 59   30 57 30 55 16 09 69 6D  0_.].[0Y0W0U..im
0010: 61 67 65 2F 67 69 66 30   21 30 1F 30 07 06 05 2B  age/gif0!0.0...+
0020: 0E 03 02 1A 04 14 8F E5   D3 1A 86 AC 8D 8E 6B C3  ..............k.
0030: CF 80 6A D4 48 18 2C 7B   19 2E 30 25 16 23 68 74  ..j.H.,...0%.#ht
0040: 74 70 3A 2F 2F 6C 6F 67   6F 2E 76 65 72 69 73 69  tp://logo.verisi
0050: 67 6E 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 76   73 6C 6F 67 6F 2E 67 69  gn.com/vslogo.gi
0060: 66                                                 f


#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: B6 77 FA 69 48 47 9F 53   12 D5 C2 EA 07 32 76 07  .w.iHG.S.....2v.
0010: D1 97 07 19                                        ....
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: xrampglobalca [jdk]
Creation date: Aug 25, 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=XRamp Global Certification Authority, O=XRamp Security Services Inc, OU=www.xrampsecurity.com, C=US
Issuer: CN=XRamp Global Certification Authority, O=XRamp Security Services Inc, OU=www.xrampsecurity.com, C=US
Serial number: 50946cec18ead59c4dd597ef758fa0ad
Valid from: Mon Nov 01 11:14:04 CST 2004 until: Sun Dec 31 23:37:19 CST 2034
Certificate fingerprints:
         SHA1: B8:01:86:D1:EB:9C:86:A5:41:04:CF:30:54:F3:4C:52:B7:E5:58:C6
         SHA256: CE:CD:DC:90:50:99:D8:DA:DF:C5:B1:D2:09:B7:37:CB:E2:C1:8C:FB:2C:10:C0:FF:0B:CF:0D:32:86:FC:1A:A2
Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2 Criticality=false

i need to 2 step solution ...
Step 1: Identify the value of Owner: CN= for all Alias name: and consider only if that value of CN= which is not the value of Issuer: CN=
Step 2: Once identified the Alias name from Step 1, I wish to get the below details for that Alias
`Alias name: ` value
`Owner: CN=` value 
`Signature algorithm name:` value
`Subject Public Key Algorithm:` value
`Valid from:` value
`until:` value

Expected output:
verisignuniversalrootca [jdk]
VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority
SHA256withRSA
2048-bit RSA key
Tue Apr 01 19:00:00 CDT 2008
Tue Dec 01 17:59:59 CST 2037

Note: the above is just a sample data which is incomplete.
You can choose <jdk_home>/jre/lib/security/cacerts on your systems for a more realistic and reproducible example.
I tried the below so far but it look its growing unclean so i m asking experts.
keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts -storepass "changeit" | awk '/Alias name:/ {print $3} /Owner: CN=/ {print substr($0, index($0,$4))}' | awk -F, '{print $1}'

I tried to convert cacerts to pkcs12 format and then print all client certs using openssl but it does not display all client cert information.
Convert to PKCS12:
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cacerts -srcstorepass "changeit" -destkeystore my_cert.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass "changeit" -noprompt

Display Client certs:
openssl pkcs12 -in /home/wladmin/my_cert.p12 -passin pass:'changeit' -passout pass:'changeit' -info -nokeys -clcerts -legacy

MAC: sha256, Iteration 10000
MAC length: 32, salt length: 20
PKCS7 Encrypted data: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 10000, PRF hmacWithSHA256
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag

Kindly suggest.

Did you look at the RFC that defines X.509v3? In there you can find how to build trust paths and such. I'm still not entirely clear what kind of certs you are looking for? Are you looking for leaf certs (i.e. certs that are not used to sign other certificates?). The RFC is also full of the right jargon to use.

@MaartenBodewes correct I need leaf certificate that cannot / does not sign other certificates. Can you share solutions/commands please?

You'd normally filter on the basic constraints of the certificate. The key usage bits can also help as cert signing is a specific key usage. You'd normally not do anything with the DN for this purpose. No I don't have a script, but with these hints you should be able to come up with one yourself. Normally you'd of course try and do this after ASN.1 decoding of the cert, but that's not normally done in shell scripts / terminals. I'd be slightly worried about people creating a certificate that contained similar information in a different (user defined) field.

Do you have sample cert file for testing?

@AnishB. if you have java on your system you can get sample cacerts here <jdk_home>/jre/lib/security/cacerts

@Ashar Got it. I have created my own. I'm writing the script for you. I will keep you posted. A bit complicated requirement you have.

Please don't add multiple problems. I'm already on my way to solve it.

@AnishB. would u also be able to look at the approach converting to my_cert.p12 and then using openssl to list client(leaf) certs using -clcerts options as mentioned at the bottom of my updated original post?

@Ashar I will check after I solve the first problem. First I'm trying to solve the alias problem.

openssl pkcs12 -clcerts doesn't really mean client certs or even EE certs; it means certs matching a privatekey i.e. for the keystore's owner. Certs in a truststore like cacerts are for entities other than the owner, usually CAs and often root CAs but can be EEs, and don't match a privatekey and thus are selected by -cacerts. See (my) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932436/why-openssl-pkcs12-in-keystore-p12-out-client-certificate-pem-clcerts-nokey . But openssl isn't going to give you any info keytool doesn't.

"I wish to list only the signed certificates for our application and not the chain signing certificate from a java store". You mean you want to find all the signed certificates from a keystore for which the signer is not inside cacerts?

Updated answer to latest requirements. please check the answers and accept one of them.

I have created a cacerts.jks on my local with the help of this Oracle Documentation.
I have executed this keytool command given below to demonstrate what I had in my JKS file for reference:
➜  ~ keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass "changeit"
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: alias-1
Creation date: 27-Aug-2024
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=localhost-1, OU=localhost-1, O=localhost-1, L=localhost-1, ST=localhost-1, C=L1
Issuer: CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=localhost, L=localhost, ST=localhost, C=LO
Serial number: cdc993ae62b5af06
Valid from: Mon Aug 26 12:48:12 IST 2024 until: Sun Nov 24 12:48:12 IST 2024
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: 7A:CA:34:2B:A1:93:78:01:DC:C2:44:49:65:B2:7E:19:46:4C:0D:5F
     SHA256: 47:71:55:78:C1:BC:B9:E8:D1:B2:35:47:D9:0D:07:1D:76:2B:1F:52:63:C5:D1:73:F8:9C:AE:F6:BE:6E:C8:04
Signature algorithm name: SHA384withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 3072-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 16 29 19 7A A7 C8 64 1D   B2 6B E0 C7 79 0C 19 51  .).z..d..k..y..Q
0010: 25 14 FA 33                                        %..3
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: server-alias
Creation date: 27-Aug-2024
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=localhost, L=localhost, ST=localhost, C=LO
Issuer: CN=localhost-1, OU=localhost-1, O=localhost-1, L=localhost-1, ST=localhost-1, C=L1
Serial number: be304468d71fdc68
Valid from: Mon Aug 26 12:24:54 IST 2024 until: Sun Nov 24 12:24:54 IST 2024
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: 18:BD:21:E0:A0:9A:E4:20:39:CA:F5:2F:C3:F5:D3:0F:B4:D5:EA:2B
     SHA256: 4D:6F:1E:27:1B:9C:04:58:87:B2:52:04:03:35:C1:30:63:3F:5C:0F:53:44:42:3E:CD:10:E3:65:7D:E0:3A:DC
Signature algorithm name: SHA384withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 3072-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: C6 73 77 B3 9E E2 5C 84   B8 3C C6 D0 E2 38 C9 F9  .sw...\..<...8..
0010: 93 9C 71 D4                                        ..q.
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************

Solution:
Use this script given below:
#!/bin/bash

aliases=($(keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass "changeit" | grep 'Alias name:' | awk -F: '{print $2}'))
for i in "${aliases[@]}"; do
    cn_owner=$(keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass "changeit" -alias $i | awk 'NR==5 {print $2}' | sed 's/,//g' | awk -F= '{print $2}')
    cn_issuer=$(keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass "changeit" -alias $i | awk 'NR==6 {print $2}' | sed 's/,//g' | awk -F= '{print $2}')
    if [ $cn_owner == $cn_issuer ]; then
        continue
    else
        echo $i
        echo $cn_owner
        keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass "changeit" -alias $i | awk 'NR==8 {print $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8}'
        keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass "changeit" -alias $i | awk 'NR==8 {print $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15}'
        keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass "changeit" -alias $i | awk 'NR==12 {print $4}'
        keytool -v -list -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass "changeit" -alias $i | awk 'NR==13 {print $5, $6, $7}'
    fi
    echo "---------"
done

Output on my local:
alias-1
localhost-1
Mon Aug 26 12:48:12 IST 2024
Sun Nov 24 12:48:12 IST 2024
SHA384withRSA
3072-bit RSA key
---------
server-alias
localhost
Mon Aug 26 12:24:54 IST 2024
Sun Nov 24 12:24:54 IST 2024
SHA384withRSA
3072-bit RSA key
---------


I have converted my JKS file to PKCS12 file using keytool command given below:
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cacerts.jks -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore cacerts.p12 -deststorepass "changeit" -noprompt

You have to use this openssl command to see all client certificate information:
openssl pkcs12 -in cacerts.p12 -passin pass:'changeit' -passout pass:'changeit'

Output on my local:
➜  ~ openssl pkcs12 -in cacerts.p12 -passin pass:'changeit' -passout pass:'changeit' -info
MAC: sha256, Iteration 10000
MAC length: 32, salt length: 20
PKCS7 Encrypted data: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 10000, PRF hmacWithSHA256
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: server-alias
    2.16.840.1.113894.746875.1.1: <Unsupported tag 6>
subject=C = LO, ST = localhost, L = localhost, O = localhost, OU = localhost, CN = localhost
issuer=C = L1, ST = localhost-1, L = localhost-1, O = localhost-1, OU = localhost-1, CN = localhost-1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: alias-1
    2.16.840.1.113894.746875.1.1: <Unsupported tag 6>
subject=C = L1, ST = localhost-1, L = localhost-1, O = localhost-1, OU = localhost-1, CN = localhost-1
issuer=C = LO, ST = localhost, L = localhost, O = localhost, OU = localhost, CN = localhost
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEnDCCAwSgAwIBAgIJAM3Jk65ita8GMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBDAUAMHwxCzAJBgNV
BAYTAkwxMRUwEwYDVQQIDAxsb2NhbGhvc3QtMVwxFDASBgNVBAcTC2xvY2FsaG9z
dC0xMRQwEgYDVQQKEwtsb2NhbGhvc3QtMTEUMBIGA1UECxMLbG9jYWxob3N0LTEx
FDASBgNVBAMTC2xvY2FsaG9zdC0xMB4XDTI0MDgyNjA3MTgxMloXDTI0MTEyNDA3
MTgxMlowfDELMAkGA1UEBhMCTDExFTATBgNVBAgMDGxvY2FsaG9zdC0xXDEUMBIG
A1UEBxMLbG9jYWxob3N0LTExFDASBgNVBAoTC2xvY2FsaG9zdC0xMRQwEgYDVQQL
Ewtsb2NhbGhvc3QtMTEUMBIGA1UEAxMLbG9jYWxob3N0LTEwggGiMA0GCSqGSIb3
DQEBAQUAA4IBjwAwggGKAoIBgQC9REFp1mlnyQBhgp2b0IdEBjRKZLyJGipjnZmF
k1nd4SOjmY6RnxDXAnuJnxObWXEywPrpahUOF9y2no4RdnpkP2BsEjmVJXP6+g2X
KDjWzqC5VaOrxJjQiHknXziV+34bS9V0M6g3fQKV/TeySIRJa7L+pfikp/C6agIz
tOjjMTvHh+LpOQriwXgLYZhiHClWGR1SRQULY3O2SyqJ1hubz2k+TuruwvLyBuPt
cfiy1GxU45YDiJlKVmoa5mkbjck3bsNfjjpCnS9Q8CARun/HE20OAKsTCBcHCc4S
ZknxGrUHd+V8jBWk+c2qirDn0RCEXXlzQw8i035ONe9FkfI1/Yo2CRVhO0Obna7w
OTytZsPC7sfw1mm0kLJydz4ZWzrZk9+3R1uKCUrtJOjBYB4pOOafGCWRuoWd6Y6P
isQoFxq1MZIOreoc9Qwy/D6iyQgrrujryQCG8opCTcL40/Zo+OceT/wDmXUR+GBp
9rGymc/NlmvXVvdER8mPEzZVx5kCAwEAAaMhMB8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFBYpGXqnyGQd
smvgx3kMGVElFPozMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBDAUAA4IBgQBcBU7DA5970AmX0HvtC5zh
bvYrNAqRFm6iIJakol6GEQIyvPtPb3MA7FtwTkCnhLD1zAM1C+xIyL85G1Ww2B7A
/CdWI5dSvA9hQve69dYI/zHiyMJDcDcclQNrV1S+kaUii/VtVhXMKYMK7GtwF/3d
rr4Jy7eDPzIRxWHyA+sd2Y7ZtwNhuNXuZTa5veCrbO3FfdO6ygLhSY5CFtY8KBn7
8Knb9JpxJF+/pSPMC+sk46b0OsWH6IojQlZvkh8BCbla9/RgpnwKxkebjZcVqaP7
KWgVL36/EtdWzdgPPxnV139ZI3zGq9syioTLhZ+/3i4MWmuIy6KDHUCKC1s6quy2
FKg00a+eu49bfmNBSG3vAfXC71sXH6C4zwSpX1tVzOzQ9yOLl7Fc6+Ya/bb3xIY2
kkfBJedpwi4lQQqIdG99uL0IhzdoMEC2JjwdVdhSmmhuQzWk8Z2brr2amxNJy6gi
94v1bPnKQppQC4kZ1by913/bUzgyRd8X2QVN3vPu2HM=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

